# Vector Subspace Structure with additive identity as e, and multiplicative as identity as pi?

Tags: vector-spaces

There is a challenge question that I am struggling to asnwer. It asks to find a subspace structure with unique operations for addition such that the additive identity is e. (n + e = e + n = n). Does this mean to define addition in such a way that this is true or just make the assumption. I decided to go with something along the lines of x + y = ln(e^(x + y - e)), however I am not sure this is what the question is asking.

Comment: The exact text of the question would help. I find it suspicious that the question is asking for a unique definition of the operations, but also wanting a subspace structure, which means that the operations must be inherited from the vector space the substructure is included in.

Comment: The exact wording of the question is as follows: Come up with a real vector space structure on R where the additive identity is e (Euler’s
number). Either prove that your example is a vector space, or explain why no such example
exists.

Comment: Why are you taking the logarithm of an exponential? Simply defining $x*y$ to be $x+y-e$ turns the reals into an abelian group with identity $e$. To be a vector space, you also need a scalar multiplication.

Comment: I know, but this specific can use normal multiplication as only the additive identity is being changed. Part b does, however, require a new definition. I was just looking for a bit of clarification on this part and I should be able to answer the rest.